# Angular 2 - When I get a firebase call back it doesnt know what this.newUser is and is undefined

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular

When I get a firebase call back it doesnt know what this.newUser is. I get undefined. It seems that it doesnt understand the scope.

How can I see the this.newUser object populated in the callback?

I hard code the this.newUser object in the constructor.

I want it to know what it is so I can add the object to a firebase table.

**Current Code:**

```
  import {Component, View, bootstrap, bind, provide} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import {Router, ROUTER_BINDINGS, RouterOutlet, RouteConfig, RouterLink, ROUTER_PROVIDERS, APP_BASE_HREF} from 'angular2/router';
  import {Injectable} from 'angular2/angular2';
  import {HTTP_PROVIDERS, Http, Headers} from 'angular2/http';

  import {Todo} from './components/todo/todo';
  import {About} from './components/about/about';
  import {AuthService} from './authService';
  import {EnvironmentService} from './environmentService';

  import {AngularFire, FirebaseArray} from '../firebase/angularfire';

  @Component({
    selector: 'app'
  })

  @View({
      template: `
          <div class="container">
              <nav>
                  <ul>
                    <li><a [router-link]="['/Home']">Todo</a></li>
                    <li><a [router-link]="['/About']">About</a></li>                
                    <li><a (click)="createUser()">Create new user and profile</a></li>
                  </ul>
              </nav>
              <router-outlet></router-outlet>
          </div>
      `,
      directives: [RouterOutlet, RouterLink]
  })

  @RouteConfig([
      { path: '/', redirectTo: '/home' },
      { path: '/home', component: Todo, as: 'Home' },
      { path: '/about', component: About, as: 'About' }
  ])

  @Injectable()
    export class AppComponent {
      firebaseUserService:FirebaseArray;
      users: AngularFire;   
      user: any;
      newUser: any;

      constructor(_router: Router, _authService: AuthService){          
          this.users = new AngularFire(new Firebase('https://markng2.firebaseio.com/users'));
          this.firebaseUserService = this.users.asArray();  

          this.newUser = {"email":"@gmail.com", "password":"password", "uid": null};
    }   

      public addUser(error, response){

          //Doesnt know what this is: this.newUser is undefined????
          console.log(this.newUser);

          //this.newUser.uid = response.uid;
          //this.firebaseUserService.add(this.newUser);
      }

      public createUser(){
        var ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com");   
          ref.createUser(this.newUser, this.addUser);
      }
  }

  bootstrap(AppComponent, [ROUTER_PROVIDERS, provide(APP_BASE_HREF, {useValue: '/'}), HTTP_PROVIDERS, AuthService, EnvironmentService]);
```

Comment: When I call : ref.createUser(this.newUser, this.addUser); it seems to loose scope. Therefore, this.newUser is undefined. Any ideas why? and how to resolve it?

Comment: Can you try to create this in plnkr? That would make it easier for me to debug.

Comment: Hi, I'm not sure how to do that. Do I need to make a new instance of the class in order to have access to the addUser object?

Comment: @AngularM try with `this.newUser.bind(this)` and `this.addUser.bind(this)`

Comment: Thanks Eric. It seems that callbacks loose the this, is that correct? Also, Is bind the best way vs instance of a class in order to call another method from within another methods callback?

Comment: @Eric Martinez - see above. Thanks

Comment: I would say yes, and sorry for not giving you a definitive answer, this is one of the few things I've learned while I'm learning angular2 as well. Many answers have pointed to that solution. You can read about [`bind method`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this) so you can understand better what it does.

Comment: @Eric Martinez thanks for your response. I had a read. If I call this.addUser.bind(this) then do this.addUser() from another functions callback, won't I get undefined because this is undefined when binding?

Comment: Hi @Eric Martinez I've found that fat arrow function solved my issues with loosing reference to this in a callback. I was wondering if you could take a look at this other issue in having. I've posted a new question at this stack overflow link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33858982/firebase-get-object-by-userid-from-a-list-of-profiles