# Firebase - Get object by userID from a list of profiles

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, angular

I'm trying to  get an object by userID from a list of profiles using Firebase.

I'm coding in Angular2 with Typescript.
I've got the reference to firebase working and can do other commands like push an object etc.

I just need to know how to extract an object by its field value e.g. uid in this case.

**Here's my code snippet:**

```
getUserProfileByUid(uid){
    console.log("Get profile by uid");

    var ref = new Firebase("https://markng2.firebaseio.com/profiles/uid");
    var data = ref.child(uid);

    console.log(data));     
}
```

*See attached photo for view of my firebase profiles json.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**You can use a query.**

```
var rootRef = new Firebase('<my-firebase-app>.firebaseio.com/');
var profileRef = rootRef.child('profiles');

// order by email and then find the specific email
var query = profileRef.orderByChild('email').equalTo('myemail@email.com');

// Do a one time read of that email
query.once('value', (snap) => console.log(snap.val()));
```

[Read the Firebase documentation for more details](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries).

Comment: When I access the object in the snap.val() I can see all the fields.
However, how do I access/extra the fields because the object is named after the firebase key

e.g : -K4-BInXsk3Nyw7STHxZ